# Fetch entire object eagerly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have very complex hibernate structure with many @ManyToMany, @ManyToOne, @OneToOne etc. associations. These nested collections/objects also have their own nested objects/collections. Entire object is lazily loaded.

What I am trying to achieve is, for just one specific operation, to be able to eagerly fetch ENTIRE object.

I did some research, but all I was able to find are solutions where you need to specify each object/collection and fetch it manually.

Is there a way to fetch ENTIRE object structure without the need of specifying each object I need to fetch?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could configure your hibernate `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` to **true**, this will load object’s attributes without requiring transaction to be started.